# Using react-native-zip-archive, getting error, "Cannot read property 'unzip' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-zip-archive for unzipping a zip file. While running on ios emulator, the project build fails stating "Cannot read property 'unzip' of undefined". I have performed all the required steps to add the library correctly.

Comment: Please post your code. Are you importing it correctly?

Comment: Yes

`import unzip from 'react-native-zip-archive';`

I did



`npm install react-native-zip-archive --save`
----
`react-native link react-native-zip-archive`

Comment: There's a big difference between _destructuring_ and regular importing. According to their NPM page you need to do it like this: `import { zip, unzip, unzipAssets, subscribe } from 'react-native-zip-archive'`. The latter three are optional; just make sure you use the braces.

Comment: @G0dsquad I did that, but no luck. :(

Comment: @G0dsquad I am not sure what worked but there were too many errors coming up and finally it has worked. Although I did use the '{}', so maybe that was the reason. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I'll put this as an answer then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the package's [entry on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zip-archive) you need to do it like this: `import { zip, unzip, unzipAssets, subscribe } from 'react-native-zip-archive'`.

The latter three are optional; just make sure you use the braces.